# Simple ticket reservation in Java

Tags: java

Consider:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Ticket_reserve {

  private static int counter=100;
  List<String> BookingList=new ArrayList<String>();
  ArrayList<Integer> AgeList=new ArrayList<Integer>();

  public void reservation(){
    System.out.println("Enter the tickets needed:");
    Scanner tkts=new Scanner(System.in);
    int tickets=tkts.nextInt();
    if(tickets<=counter){
      System.out.println("Name and age please");
      System.out.println("age:");
      Scanner age=new Scanner(System.in);
      int Age=age.nextInt();
      if(Age<18){
        System.out.println("You're under 18.Booking cancelled");
      }else{
        for(int i=0;i<tickets;i++){
          System.out.println("Name:");
          Scanner nom=new Scanner(System.in);
          String name=nom.nextLine();
          BookingList.add(name);
          AgeList.add(Age);
          counter--;
        }
      }
    }else{
      System.out.println(tickets+"tickets  unavailable");
    }
    System.out.println("Names: "+BookingList+","+"Age:"+AgeList);
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ticket_reserve t1=new Ticket_reserve();
    t1.reservation();
  }
}
```

This is my code and it works perfectly. The only problem I have is I need to check the age of each person and then book the ticket for that person (if they are above 18); else cancel it. I couldn't get a better idea, so I put it inside the *if*, checking for ticket availability and now I can only get the age of one person. I need to iterate through each person and print their age. Should I use a *while* loop instead?

Comment: No such thing as "simple" ticket reservation...

Comment: The `for loop` is a shorthand that avoids you to write a `while loop` and prevents you from forgetting the increment and finishing in infinite loop. So no, don't replace it with a `while loop`.IMHO, avoid `while loops` as much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you are taking just one person? You should use a loop for taking more than one person. Second, you should have a person class for [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

Let us come to your question:

After taking the properties of people, you should create a Person with this information. And add it to Person list (no need to have age list). Once you take people into a list, you can iterate on the list:

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

// Take people information from the console and add it to the list:
Person person = new Person(age, name, etc);
people.add(person);

for(Person p:people) {
    if(p.getAge < 18) { // Say something
    }
    else { // Say something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably best to use a *for* loop.

I.e.,

```
for (each ticket) {
    // <Ask for age>
}
// <...etc...>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more with designing the class.

Create a **private Boolean instance for age**, say `private boolean isAdult;`

**Initialize it in the constructor** for that instance of the class, and then you can just **use a getter** to see if the **age is valid.**

```
If yes, move on with other calculation;
else just return with an error message.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very basic way to develop your code.

You are not using the best feature of [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming), "**class**"

1. The most important entity in your program is the passenger details.
2. So better you create a class, **passenger**, with **name and age**  as variables and methods **passenger(String name, int age)** and **getDetails()**.
3. Why have you created a scanner object that many times? Once created scanner object, it can be used in all cases.
4. Use only one List or LinkedList. I suggest to store the passenger objects. And then iterate through it during printing.
5. You can make the **code work anyway**, but you can’t **work with that code**